# Linux hibernate: how to specify a swap partition to store data if I have two?

Tags: linux, swap, hibernate, hibernation

We can specify the swap partition to load data from when recovering from a `systemd` hibernation using kernel argument `resume=/dev/xxx`.

However, I didn't find any command-line or kernel argument to choose which partition to swap into.

`$ sudo systemctl hibernate    # nowhere to specify swap partition.`

If I have two active swap partitions, what will the system do?

Answer (score 4):

If you define the `resume=/dev/sdX` swap partition in your boot loader, the system know where to suspend when you launch the hibernate command. So define in Grub your resume line (install it if needed) and enjoy !

Comment: Does it means that `resume=` specifies the partition for both resuming and hibernation?

Comment: Of course, as the resuming is the wake up of the hibernation.